# Unable to create in mysql running in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a flask application in which mysql database is running in a docker-compose.
Below is my docker-compose and flask application init file.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis:6.2.5-alpine'
    network_mode: 'host'
  database:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    network_mode: 'host'
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'Myscretpassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'dev'
      MYSQL_USER: 'd1105'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'Password123'

from flask import Flask
import redis
from flask_session import Session
import logging
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy



logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
key = None
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
    app.secret_key = "my scret key"

    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
    app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
    app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379')
    server_session = Session(app)

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://d1105:Password123@localhost:3306/dev"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)


    from EIS.EISApp.child.routes import child
    from EIS.EISApp.main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(child)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    logger.info("Inside create app")
    return app
```

And the model file is

```
from EIS.EISApp import db
from datetime import datetime

print("TESTING")


class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    middlename = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    child_dob = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    child_gender = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lastwritten = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='child', lazy=True)
    # phonenumber = db.relationship('PhoneNumber', backref='child', lazy=True)
    # familyInfo = db.relationship('FamilyInformation', backref='child', lazy=True)
    # diagnosis = db.relationship('Diagnosis', backref='child', lazy=True)


class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address1 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    address2 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    county = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    zip = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('child.id'), nullable=False)
```

I am able to conect to the database while DBeaver however when I am trying to create the table using python cli , the tables are not getting created and there is no error in db server

[image: Screenshot from 2021-08-09 17-02-09]

DB server

[image]

Its been 2 hours and I am not able to figure out what is the cause of tables not been created.Could someone please help me out.Thanks

Comment: I'd say you never imported the models, so your db object is not aware of the Child and Address models.

Comment: This is the second time I have made the same import mistake. I will make sure this doesn't happen gain.Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like I was missing the required imports. Thank you Victor for pointing that out.